# Reset Database using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to write a script that will reset a database. I have an export that I am using that I can import using phpMyAdmin. The SQL file is in the same location as the script I am using.

When I run this I am getting an error in the sql file pretty early on in the file.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$mysqli->query('SET foreign_key_checks = 0');
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES"))
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
        $mysqli->query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$row[0]);
    }
}

$mysqli->query('SET foreign_key_checks = 1');



$sql_filename = 'clean.sql';
$sql_contents = file_get_contents($sql_filename);
$result = $mysqli->query($sql_contents) or die("Database query failed: ".$mysqli->error);

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: I don't think that query method can execute more than one query at once (unless they are connected with Union), so you'd have probably to somehow split queries from the clean.sql file to perform one query at each call of mysqli::query

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a multi_query() to insert all the data

```
$result = $mysqli->multi_query($sql_contents) or die("Database query failed: ".$mysqli->error);
```

See here;
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute more than one statement in a call to `mysqli::query()`, whereas I assume your `clean.sql` contains many.

You may want to read your file one statement at a time (`;` is the statement delimiter by default), or better, make a system call to the `mysql` client with something like this:

```
<?php
    exec("/path/to/mysql -D [your_database] < /path/to/clean.sql");
```